# How do I send data in C from two children to parent using pipes?

Tags: c, pipe, fork

I have this assignment where I have to create two children using fork. The parent has to send those children some letters and receive back a number. The communication has to be done using pipes.
What I can't figure out is why my code manages to send the letters to the children but then just hangs doing nothing. At first I thought it was because of the waitpid() calls but it doesn't seem to be the case. What baffles me is that if I stop reading in one of the child processes and just send a random number everything else works as expected.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define PIPE_1 0 // write to 1st child
#define PIPE_2 1 // write to parent from 1st child
#define PIPE_3 2 // write to 2nd child
#define PIPE_4 3 // write to parent from 2nd child

int main()
{
    pid_t p1, p2;
    int pipes[4][2];
    FILE *read[4], *write[4];

    int k;
    for (k = 0; k < 4; k++){
        if (-1 == pipe(pipes[k]) ){
            perror("Error creating pipe");
            exit(k+1);
        }
        read[k] = fdopen(pipes[k][0], "r");
        write[k] = fdopen(pipes[k][1], "w");
    }

    if (-1 == (p1 = fork()) ){
        perror("Error, failed to fork first child");
        exit(5);
    }

    if (p1 == 0){
        // 1st child
        fclose(write[PIPE_1]);
        int caseChange = 0;
        char c;
        while( fscanf(read[PIPE_1], "%c", &c) != EOF){
            if (c >= 97 && c <= 122){
                    c -= 32;
                    caseChange++;
            }
            printf("[Process (%d)]: %c\n", getpid(), c);
        }
        fclose(read[PIPE_1]);

        fclose(read[PIPE_2]);
        fprintf(write[PIPE_2],"%d",caseChange);
        fflush(write[PIPE_2]);
        fclose(write[PIPE_2]);  
    }
    else{
        if (-1 == (p2 = fork()) ){
            perror("Error, failed to fork second child");
            exit(6);
        }

        if (p2 == 0){
            // 2nd child
            fclose(write[PIPE_3]);
            int caseChange = 0;
            char c;
            while( fscanf(read[PIPE_3], "%c", &c) != EOF){
                if (c >= 97 && c <= 122){
                    c -= 32;
                    caseChange++;
                }
                printf("[Process (%d)]: %c\n", getpid(), c);
            }
            fclose(read[PIPE_3]);

            fclose(read[PIPE_4]);
            fprintf(write[PIPE_4],"%d",caseChange);
            fflush(write[PIPE_4]);
            fclose(write[PIPE_4]);  
        }
        else{
            // Parent
            //char *string = (char*) malloc(100);
            char string[100];
            scanf("%s", string);
            int i;

            int readCaseChange, caseChange = 0;

            fclose(read[PIPE_1]);
            for (i = 0; i < strlen(string); i+=2){
                fprintf(write[PIPE_1],"%c",string[i]);
                fflush(write[PIPE_1]);
            }
            fclose(write[PIPE_1]);

            fclose(read[PIPE_3]);
            for (i = 1; i < strlen(string); i+=2){
                fprintf(write[PIPE_3],"%c",string[i]);
                fflush(write[PIPE_3]);
            }
            fclose(write[PIPE_3]);

            waitpid(p1, NULL, 0);
            fclose(write[PIPE_2]);
            fscanf(read[PIPE_2], "%d", &readCaseChange);
            fclose(read[PIPE_2]);
            caseChange += readCaseChange;

            waitpid(p2, NULL, 0);
            fclose(write[PIPE_4]);
            fscanf(read[PIPE_4], "%d", &readCaseChange);
            fclose(read[PIPE_4]);
            caseChange += readCaseChange;

            printf("%d\n", caseChange);
            fflush(stdout);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to close anything that you aren't using in every child, especially the writer side for the parent process:

```
// 1st child
fclose(write[PIPE_1]);
fclose(write[PIPE_3]);

// 2nd child
fclose(write[PIPE_1]);
fclose(write[PIPE_3]);
```

Otherwise, the child processes will keep the writer side open and prevent the pipes from closing completely, making it where you never get an EOF in the child processes.  You were partially doing this, but since the 2nd child had write[PIPE_1] open, PIPE_1 was never completely closed.